# How to see colors in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, color

I'm interested in replacing written-out colors with their actual representation. The example is shown below is on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), and I can't seem to find a way to do it within Xcode. I'm afraid that something so useful might just be a marketing gimmick.

If not, how do I do what's to the right of

```
c.circleColor    = 
c.lineColor      =
```

[image: A picture showing an xcode source code example where colors are visually represented]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Xcode *Playground*.  That's important because it's the only place (with the default settings) that you can display these colors.

**EDIT (June 23, 2016)**: After reviewing the WWDC material on new features in Xcode, images are also supported.  This is done via `image literals`.

This is taken from Apple's [Playground Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/AddColorLiteral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015166-CH50-SW1):

> 1. Open the source editor for the playground page that will contain the literal.
> 2. Place the insertion point at the location in the code for the `UIColor` or `NSColor`.
> 3. Choose `Editor > Insert Color Literal`.
>      A color literal is added at the insertion point, and the color picker opens.  The screenshot shows the color literal just inserted for the tintColor property of imageView.
>      [image]
>      Use the color picker to choose a different color for the inserted literal. In the figure below, `imageView.tintColor` has been changed to *Aqua*, which updates the color of the resulting image.
>      [image]

Comment: A little bummed out it's just the playground, but thank you regardless!

Comment: It's not just for playgrounds. In XCode, start typing "color" and use autocomplete to select `Color Literal`. Make sure you've imported `UIKit` and make sure you're in a context where a `UIColor` makes sense. XCode will insert the literal. Double click it to edit.